# Phi Coefficient Calculation For Different Data values in two Columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, coefficients

I'm trying so obtain a matrix that dysplay all the phi coefficient result for all the genes that are present in a column.

I have a dataframe, named ALL, with the following structure:

```
   Sample   Gene   Oth
0    A       G2    Miss
1    A       G3    Non
2    B       G1    Non
3    C       G4    Miss
```

What I intended to obtain was a matrix like:

```
   G1   G2   G3   G4
G1  1   phi  phi   phi
G2  phi   1  phi   phi
G3  phi phi   1    phi
G4  phi phi  phi   1
```

Where each phi is the corresponding phi coefficient value for the gene occurence column values.

Each phi value is calculated by the following formula:

```
           n11*n00 - n10-n01
phi =     --------------------
             sqrt(A*B*C*D)
```

where,

```
      y=1    y=0    total
x=1   n11    n10      A
x=0   n01    n00      B
total  C      D       n
```

n11 -> the number of samples where both G1 and G2 occur

n10 -> the number of samples where G1 occur but not G2

n01 -> the number of samples where G2 occur but not G1

n00 -> the number of samples where both G1 and G2 not occur

In example, calculating the phi coefficient for G1 and G2, is based on this table:

```
      G1     G2     total
G1     0      1       1
G2     1      1       2
total  1      2       n
```

Comment: How do you calculate the `phi` coefficient for a given cell of your output matrix?

Comment: I've edited my question, where I tr to explain the best I can to your question